# Vaadin application war file is not running in Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, vaadin7

My application excutes successfully when I run it in eclipse. Widgetset got compiled successfully. All pages get loaded as expected.
But when I create a war file in eclipse and deployed it in the Tomcat 7.0/webapps folder and then run Tomcat, I'm getting the following error messages:

> SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/SampleResponsiveApp]
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\SampleResonsiveApp\VAADIN\widgetsets\com.example.sampleresponsiveapp.widgetset.SampleresponsiveappWidgetset\3A3F399A095112F8B58229BB835C5B7E.cache.js (Access is denied).

SampleResponsiveApp.war has the following contents:

```
 1. META-INF
 2. VAADIN
     2.1 themes
           2.1.1 sampleresponsiveapptheme
                   ---- sampleresponsiveapptheme.scss
                   ---- styles.scss
     2.2 widgetsets
           2.2.1 com.example.sampleresponsiveapp.widgetset.SampleresponsiveappWidgetset
     2.3 images
 3. WEB-INF
     3.1 classes
     3.2 lib
          --- responsive-1.0.0.alpha1.jar [is the only jar file added and used by me]
          --- other jar files got generated while exporting the war from eclipse
     3.3 web.xml
```

And following is the servlet configuration in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Sampleresponsiveapp Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.sampleresponsiveapp.SampleResponsiveAppServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI class to use</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.sampleresponsiveapp.SampleresponsiveappUI</param-value>             
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.sampleresponsiveapp.widgetset.SampleresponsiveappWidgetset</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Sampleresponsiveapp Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Sampleresponsiveapp Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please let me know how to get my application war file run successfully in Tomcat 7.

Comment: "Access is denied", sounds like a configuration issue, is this the first app you deploy to this Tomcat7 instance? Is this on unix/linux? Are the file access rights / owner etc OK?

Comment: @geert3 No, this is not the first app to be launched. I have another apps running on the same tomcat server. If I don't have vaadin widget, the app runs smooth without any issue. The issue comes only with I try to add responsive add-on.

Comment: @geert3 I am on windows 7

Comment: Running out of ideas here. Please check if directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\SampleResonsiveApp\VAADIN\widgetsets\com.example.sampleresponsiveapp.widgetset.SampleresponsiveappWidgetset exists and is accessible to your tomcat installation. If unsure, use right-click/properties/Security to add more permissions. Check if the specified file is in there and is readable.

Comment: As per Vaadin, the Widgetset folder got create in that location when the widgetsets were compiled in eclipse.These files are in the war file and this is how I need to place them. And also I unziped the war file and checked the properties of the files and they are not set to read-only. I am not sure how to check if these files are accessible to tomcat container.

Comment: Read-only is not the issue since tomcat will not need to modify this. However tomcat needs to read so that's more likely the problem. Just to be sure: you did a real deploy from the war to tomcat, not unzip them into tomcat yourself? Again, please first make sure that the mentioned files are actually in that place. To add permissions, use windows file explorer, right-click and pick "properties", choose "security" tab, click "Edit" then "add", enter user name "Everyone" and check the "full control" check box. Note: this is just to see if this helps. Don't forget to limit access again later.

Comment: I used another war file related to another application which does not have widgetsets and that got executed successfully. But only this war file with compiled widgetsets is throwing that error.

Comment: I used the code given in the following link.
https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3993515